# What is the correct one word for this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary, single-word-requests

Which one is the correct one word for the sentence given below?

> Group of military operations with a set purpose, usually in one area

"Mission" ?  or "Campaign" ?

PS.  Not clear by their meanings given in the dictionaries.

Comment: When it's not clear by the meanings in dictionaries, what did two or three dictionaries suggest, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mission is narrow and specific in purpose. You go in, do a thing, and get out. A campaign is broader in purpose and less specific. You start a campaign that has missions in it.

From one of the more famous events of WWII:

> [The Invasion of Normandy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_France_Campaign_(1944)) was a [campaign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_theaters_and_campaigns_of_World_War_II) and [Omaha Beach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omaha_Beach) was a mission.